# Content Resolver Query is not finding music on sd-card

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-contentprovider, android-sdcard, android-contentresolver

I have constructed a simple query to find music on the sdcard of the Android emulator. I am using Android Studio. I placed 3 songs on the sdcard using adb push. However, the query is not finding the music files. Here is an image of the files on the sdcard in the Music folder:

[image]

Here is the code that I am using to perform the query:

```
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    // Now we can iterate over the results, first checking that we have valid data:
    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){

        // We first retrieve the column indexes for the data items that we are interested in for each song
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

        // then we use these to create a new Song object and add it to the list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            allSongsPlaylist.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

musicCursor is not null, but musicCursor.moveToNext() returns 0.

What am I doing wrong? The music files are obviously there on the sdcard, but the query doesn't see them. If I change the content URI to INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, the query is finding files in internal storage (e.g. piezo alarm), but not my music files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

If I had to guess, you are assuming that `MediaStore` knows about those files.

`MediaStore`, on its own, only indexes external storage occasionally. It has no knowledge of files that you push there via **`adb`**.

For lightweight testing, grab yourself an app from the Play Store that triggers a reindexing round. I used to use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan), but apparently it does not support Android 4.4+. There are plenty of others, like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uberullu.rescansd), that may work for you. Or, wait a day and try your tests again tomorrow, and they may get picked up automatically by then.

Developers that write files to external storage programmatically should use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to get those files indexed by `MediaStore`.

Comment: Actually, these files had been pushed to the sd-card the previous day. But your answer made me decide to quit the emulator and reload it. That seemed to do the trick. I am always reluctant to quit the emulator because it takes forever to reload. The code is now recognizing the files. Thanks.