# How to add a song from the resource directory to a playlist

Tags: java, android

I'm been working on a project that generates a playlist with all the songs from the external storage of the device, like this:

```
private long resolveContent() {
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        addMP3TestFile();
        Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
...}
```

The code works fine, the songs display in the playlist as it suppossed, but I want to add an extra song to this playlist. This song is in the `res/raw/` directory. So I figured two solutions to this, either I copy the song to the device and let the `contentResolver` include this song to the playlist or internally add this song from the `res/raw/` directory to the playlist. I have just tried the first option I mentioned but not successfully with this code to add the song to the device:

```
private void addMP3TestFile(){
    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Music/";
    String fileName = "test_file.mp3";

    File newSoundFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);
    if(!newSoundFile.exists()){
        try {
            byte[] readData = new byte[1024*500];
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.toth);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
            int i = inputStream.read(readData);

            while (i != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(readData, 0, i);
                i = inputStream.read(readData);
            }
            Log.i("song","Success! path = "+newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());

            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            Log.i("song","Error "+io.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

The song copies successfully to the device, but the `contentResolver` ignores it, so the song doesn't show in the playlist. So I don't know how to resolve this, either by the first way I mentioned or the second one. I hope you have suggestions to this problem! Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to make your contentResolver fetch these objects again so the new song will be displayed.
Are you calling resolveContent only once?

**Update:** I believe your answer is in this question: 
[Content Resolver Query is not finding music on sd-card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736746/content-resolver-query-is-not-finding-music-on-sd-card)

Comment: Yes, but i tried to call resolveContent twice and it didn't work either. It displays all the songs twice instead but not the song i added from the res/raw/ directory. It keeps ignoring the song.

Comment: Have you checked user song is being copied?

Comment: Yes i did, it copies successfully to the device. I tried to delete the song and then to launch the app again, and it copies again. But now i noticed something new. I tried to move all the songs i have in my device to an SD-card, then i launch the app again but i take the SD-card out of the device. It doesn't read the song that the app copies to the device, BUT when i set the card in again and then i launch the app, the song displays in the song's list. but only when i do all that. otherwise, it ignores the song.

Comment: So maybe it means when it mounts the SD card it creates an index of songs which your ContentResolver is reading from. When you copy a new song you gotta mount this SD card again, or do whatever to update it.

Comment: I tried to add the song before the contentResolver gets initialized, but it gets the same result. Seemingly i have to find a way to update the index of songs...

Comment: Yes, seems it is not the ContentResolver which updated this index, but MediaStore. See CommonsWare answer in the link I posted

Comment: It worked! I rescanned the file with MediaScannerConnection and initialized the contentResolver after that in onStart(), so the playlist updates everytime, Thanks for the help!!